# How to access vitual function's content when no object of the base class is made

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, virtual

I have a piece of code here implementing polymorphism. I wanted to access the content of virtual functions without affecting my previous output.

Can anybody help me with this?

```
class parent{

      private:
              int m,n;
      public:
              parent(int x,int y): m(x),n(y)
              {
                   cout<<"parent constructor called";
              }
              virtual void display()
              {
                   cout<<"\n"<<m<<"\t"<<n;
                   cout<<"\nParent display called";
              }      
      };

class child: public parent{

      private: 
               int a,b;
      public:
             child(int x,int y, int c, int d): parent(x,y),a(c), b(d)
             {
                    cout<<"\nchild constructor called";
             }
             void display()
              {
                   cout<<"\n"<<a<<"\t"<<b;
                    cout<<"\nChild display called";
              }   
      };      

int main()
{

    child c(4,5,6,7);
    parent *p=&c;
    p->display();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: "ccess the content of virtual functions without affecting my previous output." ? What is your "previous output"? What do you mean by "content of a virtual function"?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  What does your program do, and what did you expect it to do, and how do those differ?

Comment: I meant virtual funtion of parent class.My precious ouptput was:                                             parent constructor called
child onstructor called
6     7
child diplay called

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean the following

```
         void display()
          {
               parent::display();
               cout<<"\n"<<a<<"\t"<<b;
                cout<<"\nChild display called";
          }
```

Comment: I wanted to access  virtual void display()
              {
                   cout<<"\n"<<m<<"\t"<<n;
                   cout<<"\nParent display called";
              }

Comment: In this case each time display() of child is invoked, display() of parent is also invoked. I want independent call uding concept of polymorphism

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Simply redefine the function in the child class.

Answer (score 2):

You may do it directly from pointer to base class

```
int main()
{
    child c(4,5,6,7);
    parent *p=&c;
    p->parent::display();
    p->display();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: IS there any way of accessiing without using scope resolution??

Comment: by pointer to base class without casting is the only way I know

Answer (score 2):

As an additional note. Don't make virtual functions public,
make them private and use a public non-virtual function:

```
class parent {
public:
   void display() {
      cout<<"\n"<<m<<"\t"<<n;
      cout<<"\nParent display called";
      this->doDisplay();
   }
private:
  virtual void doDisplay() {}
```

};

```
class child : public parent {
private:
  void doDisplay() override {
     //No need to call parent::display anymore
    //...
  }
```

};

This way it's impossible to forget to call `parent::display`. Will avoid bugs.